# Problemas com roteamento usando o asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Ao tentar rotear uma aplicação core 2.0, não consigo chegar na controller.

```
public class GetClientController : Controller
    {
        LoadClient loadClient = new LoadClient();

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Cliente> GetCliente(double cpf)
        {
            return loadClient.GetCliente().AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
    }
```

Na controller acima, o RoutePrefix não rola, tentei esses dois namespace e não rolou:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
```

Na minha model fiz isso

```
[Route("api/getcliente/{cpf}")]
        public List<Cliente> GetCliente(Int64 cpf)
        {
            List<Cliente> cliente = new List<Cliente>();

            cliente.Add(new Cliente(123456, "p@vb.com", "986754007", "CB", "EML"));
            cliente.Add(new Cliente(908734, "x@cb.com", "988877731", "CB", "SMS"));
            cliente.Add(new Cliente(674300, "p@pf.com", "965241131", "PF", "EML"));
            cliente.Add(new Cliente(101654, "p@ex.com", "987450101", "EX", "EML"));
            cliente.Add(new Cliente(501274, "p@pa.com", "986754144", "PA", "SMS"));

            var lista = cliente
                .Where(cp => cp.Cpf == cpf).ToList();

            return lista;
        }
```

quando eu testo no postman, não me dá erro, mas não obtenho a lista passada. Esse é o postman:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT1**

Fiz essa edição e removi da model e mesmo assim não entra no método

```
public class GetClientController : Controller
    {
        LoadClient loadClient = new LoadClient();

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/getcliente/{cpf}")]
        public IEnumerable<Cliente> GetCliente(Int64 cpf)
        {
            return loadClient.GetCliente(cpf).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT2**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT3**
Meu Startap.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        }
```

**EDIT4**

Fiz essa alteração e mesmo assim não rolou

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class GetClientController : Controller
    {
        LoadClient loadClient = new LoadClient();

        [HttpGet("getcliente/{cpf}")]
        public IEnumerable<Cliente> GetCliente(Int64 cpf)
        {
            return loadClient.GetCliente(cpf).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Se colocou o roteamento na model? o roteamento é na classe do Controller!

Comment: Não sei o que você fez, só sei que na sua pergunta a rota está no lugar errado tem que ser no controller ! e também a rota está com problemas!

Comment: Faz o seguinte no lugar de cpf coloque `id`(`[Route("api/getcliente/{id}")]`) e no paramentro `int id`(`public IEnumerable<Cliente> GetCliente(int cpf)`) também...

Comment: Tente remover o "api" do Route que está em cima do seu método.

Comment: Se seu método GetCliente espera um parâmetro, você tem que passar um parâmetro pra ele, do contrário, não irá achar nada mesmo. Observe que no seu postman, o método que chamou é getclient e não getcliente.

Comment: Como você fez esse projeto? Como a gente observou tem bastante problemas o seu código e isso pode fazer com que não funcione corretamente !!!

Comment: Procure por routes.MapRoute dentro da classe Startup.cs e coloque o código aqui, por favor.

Comment: Será necessário algum atributo de classe na  **Rota**? Tentei o **RoutePrefix** e não consegui.

Comment: @perozzo, o .Net Core não tem isso

Comment: Ah não? Eu uso .Net Core 2.0 e meu projeto tem isso.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, esse projeto é só um mock para testar um outro serviço. Ele não é só isso mesmo e para testes. Precisei fazê-lo às pressas e não funfou.

Comment: @perozzo, printei o meu projeto e veja que não tenho essa pasta

Comment: É um arquivo e não uma pasta. Presta atenção. Tá na tua frente o arquivo e tu não viu.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79057/discussion-between-perozzo-and-pnet).

Comment: Tu leu o que eu comentei? Vamos denovo: Procure por routes.MapRoute dentro da classe Startup.cs e coloque o código aqui, por favor.

Comment: @perozzo, editei o post e postei o startup

Comment: Aí está o problema. Seu arquivo Startup.cs está bem distante do que deveria estar.

Comment: Entendi, falta o MapRoute, certo? Estou procurando um exemplo em como configurar esse cara

Comment: Quando criou o projeto do zero ele já não veio com o MapRoute pronto pra vc?

Comment: Veja também o *ASP Net Core 2 Razor Pages*, que simplifica tudo isto.

Answer (score 0):

No Aspnet Core não existe mais o annotation `RoutePrefix`, agora tanto para o annotation da Classe quando da Action se usa o `Route`, como vc fez.

Porém quando vc cria a rota `[Route("api/getcliente/{cpf}")]`, vc está dizendo que a propriedade cpf será recebida de alguma maneira.
Somado a isso, vc usa um `[HttpGet]`, então vc quer passar o cpf pela própria url.

Sabendo disso, o print do postman mostra que vc não está informando a url corretamente.

Ela deveria ser: `http://localhost:55730/api/getclient/31865881384`

Se mesmo assim a Action não receber o cpf, é porque vc não deixou explícito no parâmetro que ele deverá ser recebido via url.

Para isso faça a seguinte alteração:

```
public class GetClientController : Controller
{
    LoadClient loadClient = new LoadClient();

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/getcliente/{cpf}")]
    public IEnumerable<Cliente> GetCliente([FromRoute]double cpf)
    {
        return loadClient.GetCliente().AsEnumerable().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu tenho dois métodos sobrecarregados, 1 com parâmetro e outro sem, razão de naquele momento em que capturei o print do postman, estava passando o GetAll(Sem parâmentros), foi mal não ter explicitado isso.

Comment: Fiz as alterações devidas e continua me retornando um statuscode 404(page not found)

Comment: Na verdade me confundi, o correto é FromRoute e não FromQuery. Com FromQuery vc precisaria chamar a url assim: api/getcliente?cpf=12345678

Comment: Olhando bem, a minha controller tem um ToList() para apenas um elemento. Isso pode dar pau? Porque troquei para FromRoute e mesmo assim não rolou

Comment: Fiz outra alteração(Edit4) e não rolou

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi. No Startup eu fiz:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddRouting();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

e na controller chamei

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class GetClientController : Controller
    {
        LoadClient loadClient = new LoadClient();

        [HttpGet("{cpf}")]
        public IEnumerable<Cliente> GetCliente(Int64 cpf)
        {
            return loadClient.GetCliente(cpf).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
    }
```

Com isso resolvi o problema. Obrigado a todos.